# Two input tags side by side without spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place 2 input divs side by side in HTML, using flat ui and bootstrap. I currently have this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">State <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach ($states as $key => $value)
                    <li value="{{ $states[$key]['id'] }}">{{ $states[$key]['name'] }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-group">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.input-group -->
</div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

With the code above i can achieve the image below but once i replace the button/dropdown with an input box they become stacked on one another.

So basically i want two inputs side by side without spacing

[Currently acchieving this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09pbf.png)

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline All you need to do is remove the padding between the two input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox in order to achieve this. by using flexbox [you may loose some browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) but you avoid the hacky ways like removing paddings or margins between elements.

in this situation you have to add `display: flex` to input-group.

here is the example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0g3wLohL/1/